# How do I register N Jobs in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I have a method which can be called many times

```
public void DoSomething(){
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder
                .Create<NotificationResendJob>()
                .UsingJobData(newJobDataMap)
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                  .WithIdentity("HelloWorldJob-trigger")
                                  .StartNow()
                                  .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
                                  .Build();

            var scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

It works fine, but if it is invoked more than once, then an exception is thrown because there is an instance already running.

My question is, it is possible to create a method that will build a new job and trigger  for every method invocation, supposing that this method will not be called often

For example user clicks a button and a job is triggered, another user after some time clicks this button too, and another job is triggered for him

`Unable to store Trigger: 'DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob-trigger', because one already exists with this identification.'`

Comment: Please include the full exception details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make a distinction between job and a trigger. Usually job is a logic that can be run multiple times and even multiple parameters.

Say job is GreetPerson, so you want to run this every morning, so once a day, but also for different people.

You can define an `IJob` implementation that does the `Console.Writeline` using data from job data map. Job data map consists of values from both Job (more global) and trigger (per invocation, there can be multiple different triggers).

In this case you could call

```cs
string personToGreet = context.User.DisplayName;
JobDataMap dataMap = BuildJobDataMapForThisInvocation(personToGreet);
IScheduler.TriggerJob(theJobKey, myJobParameters);
```

Then the job would retrieve invocation (trigger) specific data from map and would be reusable among different use cases.